# Error C2535: 'void NumberList::appendNode(double)' : member function already defined or declared Line 35

Tags: c++, list, pointers

In the middle of our class and currently we are stuck on the following compiling error. Not sure if it's the compiler or our code. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

**Our header file:**

```
//specification file for the numberlist class

#ifndef NUMBERLIST_H
#define NUMBERLIST_H

class NumberList
{
private:
    //declares a structure for the list
    struct ListNode
    {
        double value; // value in the node
        struct ListNode *next; //to point to the next node 

    };

    ListNode *head; // list head pointer

public: 
    // construcorr
    NumberList()
    {
        head = nullptr;
    }

    ~NumberList();
    //linked list operations
    void appendNode(double);
    void insertNode(double);
    void deleteNode(double);
    void dispayList()const;


    void NumberList::appendNode(double num)
    {
        ListNode *newNode;
        ListNode *nodePtr;

        //allocate a new node and store num there
        newNode = new ListNode;
        newNode->value = num;
        newNode->next = nullptr;
        //if there are no nodes in the listmake newNode first node
        if (!head)
            head = newNode;
        else // otherwise insert newNode at end
        {
            //initialize nodePtr to head of list
            nodePtr = head;
            //find the last node in the list
            while (nodePtr->next)
                nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
            // insert newNode as the last node
            nodePtr->next = newNode;

        }
    }

};

#endif
```

**Our CPP file:**

```
//this program demonstrates a simple append operation on a linked list
#include <iostream>
#include "NumberList.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //define a numberList object
    NumberList list;
    //append some values
    list.appendNode(2.5);
    list.appendNode(7.9);
    list.appendNode(12.6);



    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: side remark: replace `system("pause")` by the portable `std::cin.get();`. Not everyone runs Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You first declared the function in the class declaration, then also defined it inside the class declaration. You either have to move the definition outside, in a corresponding `.cpp` file that implements the class, i.e. the code below should be in the implementation `cpp` file:

```
void NumberList::appendNode(double num)
{
    // implementation
}
```

or define it inline in the class

```
class NumberList
{ 
    // .... 
    void appendNode(double num) // automatically inline
    {
        // implement
    }
};
```

A third option is to define it in the header file but outside the class, however in this case you have to explicitly mark it as `inline`, since otherwise including your header in multiple `cpp` files will lead to a linker error due to a duplicate symbol

```
inline void NumberList::appendNode(double num) // this can now be in the header file
{
    // implementation
}
```

You cannot have both a declaration **and** a definition inside a class.

Comment: Doing the first (moving `void NumberList::appendNode(double num) {}` to just above our int main in our implemented cpp file, returns the following error, `Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall NumberList::~NumberList(void)" (??1NumberList@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main`

Comment: The new code with suggested edits: https://gist.github.com/markbratanov/b73278a7d2573ac1ffd9

Comment: @markbratanov you need to create another `cpp` file in which to implement the class, call it `NumberList.cpp`. You must `#include "NumberList.h" inside, and define your class member functions. Or, just define all functions inside the class, as I mentioned in the 2nd code snippet. You are getting linker errors because you just declared the destructor, but didn't implement it (defined). You must implement all functions (at least the one you are using).

Answer (score 1):

You have to close class declaration end brace before starting function definition.
//specification file for the numberlist class

```
#ifndef NUMBERLIST_H
#define NUMBERLIST_H

class NumberList
{
private:
    //declares a structure for the list
    struct ListNode
    {
        double value; // value in the node
        struct ListNode *next; //to point to the next node 

    };

    ListNode *head; // list head pointer

public: 
    // construcorr
    NumberList()
    {
        head = nullptr;
    }

    ~NumberList();
    //linked list operations
    void appendNode(double);
    void insertNode(double);
    void deleteNode(double);
    void dispayList()const;
};


    void NumberList::appendNode(double num)
    {
        ListNode *newNode;
        ListNode *nodePtr;

        //allocate a new node and store num there
        newNode = new ListNode;
        newNode->value = num;
        newNode->next = nullptr;
        //if there are no nodes in the listmake newNode first node
        if (!head)
            head = newNode;
        else // otherwise insert newNode at end
        {
            //initialize nodePtr to head of list
            nodePtr = head;
            //find the last node in the list
            while (nodePtr->next)
                nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
            // insert newNode as the last node
            nodePtr->next = newNode;

        }
    }


#endif
```

Comment: If you define the member function inside the header but outside the class, you should mark it `inline`, otherwise, including the header in different compilation units will lead to multiple definitions (hence a linker error due to a duplicate symbol). Best is to put it in a `.cpp`, or define it inside the class (which will then automatically be inlined).